# How to combine 3 line charts in a single chart, using the Views integration of the Charts module?

Tags: 7, views, charts

I want to create a [line graph using the  Highcharts library](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic) which shows 3 series in a single chart. I have visualization API, views, highcharts library etc. installed in my Drupal website.

I succeeded already in creating a chart which shows only 1 serie, but couldn't get it to work with 3 series yet.

The X-axis is taxonomy terms and Y-axis is the value of nodes on this term (relationship: Taxonomy terms on node).

The view I created has a filter and it filters the views with 3 content types I wanted. So I want to show these 3 content types as 3 different series (line charts), instead of just 1 line chart with everything together.

Here are some relevant details of the view I created:

[image]

This is the line chart I was able to create so far:

[image]

Here is what I want to achieve (using data that are different though):

[image]

**How can I visualize my 3 series (for 3 different content types) in a chart similar to the above one?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After diving into deep on visualization with Drupal, [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module gives us the opportunity to do this, either by using the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) integration of [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) (to create charts without coding PHP snippets), or by using the Charts API (used as a developer module that provides a unified API for the integration of various charting solutions into Drupal).

This is from the `Readme.txt` file, incuded with the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module:

> ### Creating Multiple Series and Combo Charts in the UI
>
> When using Views to build your charts, you may find it difficult to
>   retrieve more than a single set of data generated by a COUNT() query.
>   For example if you wanted to retrieve the age of all your site users,
>   but display "Male" and "Female" values in a column chart at the same
>   time, constructing the underlying table of data is quite difficult.
>
> To solve this problem, you can combine multiple charts on top of each
>   other. The "parent" chart provides the global information, such as the
>   height, width, title, and other properties. Charts that are "children"
>   provide only data and (optionally) a secondary axis. After you've
>   assembled the first series of data in your chart according to the
>   instructions in the "Creating Charts in the UI" section, add a new
>   display to the same view of the type "Chart Add-on". The "Chart
>   Add-on" type is added the same way you would add a new Page or Block
>   display, from the "+ Add" menu at the top of the view configuration.
>
> After this new display has been added, find the setting for "Combine
>   with parent chart" and change this value to point at the parent chart
>   you have already assembled. Then adjust the settings for the child
>   chart to pull in different data (often by overriding the filter
>   settings). Now you can go back to your parent display, and see that
>   the results from the child chart have been merged into the results
>   from the parent chart. You can even use this approach to combine
>   different types of charts, such as a line chart over the top of a
>   column chart. Note that not all chart types can be combined together
>   and invalid combinations may cause your chart to throw errors.

Comment: I found a problem with the chart add-on. If my first chart (a page for example) has values for x: A, C and D and then my add-on chart has values for B, C and D, the global chart doesn't show A, B, C, D but instead, it shows A, C and D (parent chart). This is because views doesn't treat "No results" has zero.

Comment: About the prior comment from  @zephirus : refer to my answer at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/175174/how-to-create-a-combination-chart-with-the-charts-module-if-some-x-axis-values-a/179414#179414 about how to address that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some additions to the previous (accepted) answer:

- Even though the question is related to [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo) as the charting library (one of the engine used by the Charts module to actually render charts), it should also work for anybody using the (interactive) [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery) library instead. Either of both libraries have their advantages and disadvantages, simply pick the one that best fits your needs/requirements. And remember that at any time you should be able to switch between either library, though there should not be any significant difference between the rendered charts.
- The content of the `Readme.txt` file quoted in the previous answer, is now also included in the [Community Documentation about Charts](https://www.drupal.org/node/233753), i.e. within [Steps to create charts using the views UI](https://www.drupal.org/node/2426929). That community documentation also includes a subsection with [Charts HowTos](https://www.drupal.org/node/2435077).
- Whenever using the Views integration of the Charts module, keep this golden rule in mind: you may find it easier to start with a "Table" display and convert it to a chart display after setting up the data. It can be easier to visualize what the result of the chart will be if it's been laid out in a table first.

Disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of the Charts module (+ author of its community documentation),
I hope this does not violate the site's [policy on self-promotion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The **golden rule** you wrote is very important. If you couldn't show your views as table then you couldn't show it as chart.

Comment: Can't find any documentation on creating multi-series charts via API, i.e. what would be the structure of the render array (Drupal 8).