# How to create a combination chart with the Charts module if some X-axis values are missing?

Tags: 7, views, charts

I've been searching for a solution to my problem for a while without success so maybe someone here can help me.

I've already looked at the answer to the question about "[How to combine 3 line charts in a single chart, using the Views integration of the Charts module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/136723)", but that didn't help to solve my issue.

I use the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module to create a chart in [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) using the "*Chart*" display format. And I'm using [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo) as my charting library to draw the number of "Passed" nodes (in green). I also created a chart add-on to represent the number of "Failed" nodes (in red) so that I can have multiple series in the same chart.

At this moment this is the chart that I have with the problem I will describe below:

[image]

As you can see in the table above, I have 4 different dates (Run Date and Time). The chart should show the 4 dates. Instead, it only shows 3 dates and this is why: The last date doesn't have "Passed" nodes, so the chart display (the parent) does not have that value on its axis. The chart add-on, representing the 2 Faileds on the last date, is then represented on top of the first display using the 3rd date and not the 4th, giving the error.

It seems that the x-axis values are irrelevant in this module.

The chart that I want should be something like this:

[image]

I made this chart in Excel and the difference that I see (that is giving me the wrong results in Drupal) is that I don't have a "**0 Passed**" or "**0 Failed**" but instead I have no results at all.

Is there a way to get this working correctly? I tried already many charts modules available and everyone has this problem as far as I know ...

Below is also a screenprint of my view:

[image]

Note: for the table below the chart I'm using module [Views Merge Rows](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_merge_rows) and it's clear that the top two dates don't show the "**0 Failed**" or "**0 Passed**" (as shown in the tabular display of my first screenprint) needed to have a correct chart displayed.

**EDIT:** I have found the same issue [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2052429#comment-7750201) and [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2052429#comment-7751531). Hope it helps.

If there's need to have a solution like in the second link, i.e., construct the view in a way that both series will always have all labels, I'm open to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Step 1

Not sure if it's your "only" problem to get your chart right, but part of your problem is, pretty sure, that you have "holes" in your data, similar to what is detailed in [Comment nr 12](https://www.drupal.org/node/2052429#comment-8512211) of [Issue nr 2052429](https://www.drupal.org/node/2052429).

#### About the problem

To understand what that issue about "hole" is all about, consider these data to be charted:

[image]

Note that for the Types *Article* and for *Webform*, there is no row with Published = No (that is, there are no unpublished nodes for these types). So in this scenario we have 2 so called "holes" ... And that's were the trouble start:

- **Problem 1**: a column chart for these data looks like so:

  [image]

  The bar for "Article" (with value 1) is wrong, that bar is actually related to the value 1 for unpublished "Book pages". And the bar for "Book page" (with value 2) should actually be the bar for the 2 unpublished "Basic pages".
- **Problem 2**: a line chart for these data looks like so:

  [image]

  In this case, the line for "unpublished" suffers similar problems. So it doesn't matter what type of chart you're creating, all charts have this issue.

#### How to solve this problem

Upgrade to the most recent [Dev version](https://www.drupal.org/node/2050833) to start with (which is much better / stable then the current rc1 version). Then apply the [patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/charts_addons_data_holes.patch) attached to the issue comment mentioned above, and check if that helps in your case. If it doesn't, know that it is a prereq for sure (without that patch you won't be able to get it to work). **Attention**: the patch doesn't seem to apply anymore to the most recent dev version. To make it work (again), do not use the above mentioned patch, but instead use the [re-rolled patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/fix_series_gaps-2052429-31.patch) attached to in [Comment nr 31](https://www.drupal.org/node/2052429#comment-10564866) of [Issue nr 2052429](https://www.drupal.org/node/2052429).

Here is how the same column chart from above looks like after applying this correction:

[image]

And this is its corresponding line chart:

[image]

... Which I believe is the chart that exactly matches the tabular data shown above.

## Step 2

If upgrading to the most recent dev version and applying the patch is not sufficient, then I'd recommend you to (temporarily) disable that [Views Merge Rows](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_merge_rows) module you have enabled. And (temporarily) modify your view to show the values for PASSED and FAILED as 2 separated columns. And then verify if you get the correct results. That way we can verify if this Views Merge Rows module is the culprit (solve support requests is like taking away all possible causes, 1 at a time ...).

## Step 3

If step 2 doesn't help either, then I recommend what's written in the "Bonus tip" of [Steps to create charts using the views UI](https://www.drupal.org/node/2426929), i.e.:

> You may find it easier to start with a "Table" display and convert it to a chart display after setting up the data. It can be easier to visualize what the result of the chart will be if it's been laid out in a table first.

In other words: before trying to create a chart, make sure the tabular version of it has the correct data displayed.

## Step 4

If none of the previous steps helps, then you may want to check the result you get by correcting your view like so:

- Create another display in the same view, let's say you name it "*Runs Chart (Total)*". It should be equal to all the specs of "*Runs Chart (Passed)*", but without the filter "*Content: Test Case Run Status (Passed)*". Obviously, it'll reflect the total Runs (both passed and failed). I'd make it a "line chart" (but that's a matter of personal preferences).
- Adapt the "*Chart settings*" of "*Runs Chart (Passed)*" to have it use  "*Runs Chart (Total)*" as the parent chart.
- Adapt the "*Chart settings*" of "*Runs Chart (Failed)*" to have it use  "*Runs Chart (Total)*" as the parent chart (instead of "*Runs Chart (Passed)*").

## Step 5

If the work around in step 4 helps as a work around, you may want to further refine the chart settings of "*Runs Chart (Total)*", by using a color for the line chart that matches the background of your chart (like white?). Possibly something similar for any of it settings like "Legend" (like set it to `&nbsp;`?

Disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of the Charts module (+ author of its community documentation),
I hope this does not violate the site's [policy on self-promotion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).

Comment: Hi Pierre, I already tried those 3 steps. The issue, as I said before is how the module is implemented. The x-axis is always dependent on the number of labels of the parent chart.

Comment: i just added "Step 4" ... curious if that may help to get it working in your case ... Let me know, ok?

Comment: Hi Pierre, Step 4 is a good workaround but it still doesn't solve it all. With this step I don't have "holes" in the data because the parent chart has every x-axis label. But it comes with a price: I have a line that I don't want to show and a legend. Instead of counting the status field I can Sum it and the line doesn't show but still, the legend is there. Conclusion: it's a good workaround, not a solution. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Great news about Step 4! I just did 1 more attempt to have you consider my answer as (more or less) acceptable ... Maybe it also helps to not have your bounty go to the "Drupal.SE waste bin" in a few hours from now?

Comment: Hi again Pierre. About Step 5. Changing the line color is not a solution. The chart heigh adapts to show the line (even if we don't see it) and if we have data labels, they will show. My comment about the workaround is in fact the best solution till now. A final solution for this has to be done by changing the module code, there's no other way. One of the things that should be possible in the future is to have settings for both the parent and the add-on charts. I will accept your solution with the 5 steps anyway as it is the best at the moment.

Comment: "Merci beaucoup" (how good is your French???) for the accept ... And even though you granted the bounty (also "merci" ...), know that I don't "give up" yet on your question here (apart from enhancing the charts module code). Here is yet another attempt for a variation of step 5: how about you use "rewrite results" for that "Runs chart (total)", to just set it to "0" (so that it would NOT adapt the charts height) ... And combine it with a black line chart. Wanna try one more time in your setup?

Comment: I didn't use rewrite. I used SUM aggregation. Because the field is a string, it returned 0. As I said, it's a workaround, it's not completely bad for my needs. The data values (zeros) still show on x-axis tought :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you need to do is construct the view in a way that both series will always have all labels.

To do this, all you need to do is make sure the "Count the number 0 as empty" field is unchecked. To find this field, click on the field name that you're counting to bring up its config overlay. Select "No Results Behavior" and make sure that the "Count the number 0 as empty" checkbox is unchecked. "Hide if empty" should also be unchecked.

Does that fix your problem? If not, it would be helpful if you exported your view and posted it, or at least the section regarding the field you're counting on.

Comment: Hi Erin, that doesn't solve the problem. Imagine you have 3 nodes like this (x, y): [a, 1] [a, 2] [c, 3]. If you create a chart in views, the "b" label will never show, no matter what. The solution has to be made in charts. If you have the first display of type chart where there is labels a, b, d. Then, if you create a second display of type chart add-on and the data has only labels a, c, d, the final chart will have only 3 labels, defined in the first display. There is a workaround for this problem but implies that you create aditional fields in the db.

Comment: Oh dang, I totally misunderstood the question. Sorry!

Comment: [Here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2314455) is also a good explanation of this issue. Sadly, no solution till now :(

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like something that's going to need a patch to the module to fix.